# Show $ \coth(sx)(\coth(sx)-\frac{1}{s}\coth(x))$ is increasing

Tags: real-analysis, hyperbolic-functions

Does anyone know how to show that for $s\geq2$ fixed the function

> $$ \coth(sx)(\coth(sx)-\frac{1}{s}\coth(x))$$
>   is increasing for $x>0$ ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why $s \geq 2$ ? I have the feeling that this could be the case for $s >1$

Comment: Its just because $s\geq 2$ its enough for me :)

Comment: For sure, this is a good reason ! Cheers :-)